# mustache partial not looping through the data passed down to it

Tags: json, templates, mustache, partials, patternlab.io

I am using [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) in conjunction with [enter link description here](http://patternlab.io/)pattern lab to render out a list of items from a json data file. Given this data structure:

```
{
  "states": {
    "dropdown": {
      "items": [
        {
          "title": "CA"
        },
        {
          "title": "OR"
        },
        {
          "title": "TX"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "roles": {
    "dropdown": {
      "items": [
        {
          "title": "Mid-level Office Manager"
        },
        {
          "title": "Facility Manager"
        },
        {
          "title": "Resources Coordinator"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If I do the following within my partial:

```
{{#states}}
  {{#dropdown.items}}{{title}}{{/dropdown.items}}
{{/states}}
```

The names render out fine.

But if I do this:

```
{{#states}}
  {{> molecules-dropdown-picker(btnDropdownToggleLabel: "OR")}}
{{/states}}
```

Where the dropdown picker partial has the following code:

```
{{#dropdown.items}}{{title}}{{/dropdown.items}}
```

It won't render. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out by doing the following:

JSON:

```
{
  "states": {
    "inputTextLabel": "State",
    "inputTextName": "address_state",
    "btnDropdownToggleLabel": "OR",
    "dropdownPickerItems": [
      {
        "dropdownItemTitle": "OR"
      },
      {
        "dropdownItemTitle": "TX"
      },
      {
        "dropdownItemTitle": "UT"
      }
    ]
  },
  "roles": {
    "inputTextLabel": "Company Role",
    "inputTextName": "company_role",
    "btnDropdownToggleLabel": "Facility Manager",
    "dropdownPickerItems": [
      {
        "dropdownItemTitle": "Facility Manager"
      },
      {
        "dropdownItemTitle": "Resources Manager"
      },
      {
        "dropdownItemTitle": "Mid-level Manager"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

FORM:

```
{{#states}}
  {{> molecules-dropdown-picker-list}}
{{/states}}
```

DROPDOWN-PICKER-LIST:

```
<div class="dropdown-picker js-dropdown">
  <ul class="dropdown-picker__list js-dropdown-list">
    {{#dropdownPickerItems}}
      {{> atoms-dropdown-picker-item}}
    {{/dropdownPickerItems}}
  </ul>
</div>
```

DROPDOWN-PICKER-ITEM:

```
<li class="dropdown-picker__item js-dropdown-item">
  {{dropdownItemTitle}}
  <span class="dropdown-picker__selected-check">
    {{> atoms-icon(icon-type: "check-small") }}
  </span>
</li>
```